# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python, sqlite

I am developing this program and for some reason, I keep getting this error. Is this an Ubuntu caused error, or something in my code that it crashing my program?

I am accessing a database and trying to remove the following characters from output: and, via `value.translate(dictionary_of_bad_characters)`. That's where I get my error.

```
def get_data(plu):          # Get the data needed
    global value            # Set the variable value to global

    conn = sqlite3.connect('plus.sqlite')   # Connect to the sqlite3 database

    cursor = conn.cursor()  # Set cursor as the cursor for plus.sqlite

    results = cursor.execute('SELECT value FROM plus WHERE plu=?', [plu])
    # Above code gets the data value for value with the PLU of plu

    value = results.fetchone()            # Get the results of value

    data = [row[0] for row in results.fetchall()]

    translation_table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '+-(),'), None)
    # Above code creates a table with the mapped characters

    value = value.translate(translation_table)
    # Above code removes any unnescessary characters from value

    response = {    'PLU':      plu,
                    'Value':    value
                    }       # Create the response variable

    value = int(value)      # Convert value to type integer

    cursor.close()          # Close the cursor
    conn.close()            # Close the connection

    return(value)           # Return to the program flow
```

Comment: Why was this question posted here? I'm sure this should be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Blaszard Yes, you are technically correct, *now*. However, it's over 3 years old at this point and when it was posted the policy regarding dev questions was far more relaxed, and wasn't considered OT at the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error indicates that `value` is a tuple, and not a string as you might expect. This indicates a problem with your application.

Here the problem is that `fetchone()` returns a one-tuple. You should change from this line:

```
value = results.fetchone()
```

to this (notice the comma after `value`):

```
value, = results.fetchone()
```

or this (not recommended):

```
value = results.fetchone()[0]
```

---

But why is `fetchone()` returning a tuple instead of a string? Because you can `SELECT` multiple columns. Consider for example the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM my_table;
```

In this case, `fetchone()` will return a three-tuple.

Writing `value, = fetchone()` you are telling Python that you are expecting a one-tuple and you want that single item placed into `value`. If you were expecting the three-tuple, you'd have used `column_a, column_b, column_c = resulsts.fetchone()`.

This is the reason why you should prefer `value,` over `fetchone()[0]`.

---

**Bonus tip:** I noticed you are using Python 3. In this case, you can write:

```
translation_table = dict.fromkeys(b'+-(),', None)
```

Speeding up your code and making it more clean.

Comment: Oops, sorry (see the edit, I included the part that uses this). I knew about the fact that str is tuple and all that yadda-yadda, I just was wondering how to fix it (aka, convert to a string so I can - which, btw, `str = str(str)` also raises an error, I tried)

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: I've updated my answer saying why `str(str)` does not work.

Comment: Yeah, I know why str(str) doesn't work. I was just using that as a placeholder in my posts/comments. You can see my updated post with code.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: here you are

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up figuring it out from the Python help and Google, but I used the same thing you did. Thanks!

Comment: thanks! Python documentation really needs an overhaul!!!